# Can you get an auth code for Vodapay mini programs while in the simulator?

Tags: vodapay-miniprogram

For Vodapay mini-programs, is there a way to get an auth code while in the IDE simulator or is it only available while on the device?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make use of the `applyAuthCode` request to the test environment.

You can read more about it in [the docs](https://vodacom-miniprogram.alipay.com/docs-vodacom/miniprogram_vodacom/mpdev/ch8kwj2g).